# Popular select de paises e estados com php mysql ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, select

Tenho 2 selects: #pais e #estado.

Quero que ao selecionar o país, ele popule o estado apenas com os estados desse país, que estão gravados numa tabela mysql:

```
tabela_paises
id|pais
 1|brasil

tabela_estados
id|idpais|estado
 1|  1   |São Paulo
```

o select do país já traz por uma query, os valores da tabela_paises

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT pais FROM tabela_paises ORDER BY pais ASC");
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
$items[] = "- Nenhum -";
foreach ($results as $res){
$items[] = $res->pais;
}
return implode("\n",$items);
```

Mas para o estado não sei como fazer para pegar o id do pais como filtro, pensei em algo como abaixo, mas nesse caso o id está fixo, ele precisa ser dinamico

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT estado FROM tabela_estados WHERE idpais = 1 ORDER BY estado ASC");
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
$items[] = "-  Nenhum -";
foreach ($results as $res){
$items[] = $res->estado;
}
return implode("\n",$items);
```

Comment: Como você está fazendo para enviar a informação para o servidor?
A página é toda carregada ou por ajax? Você precisa definir como deve chegar o id do estado por parâmetro na requisição.

Answer (score 0):

Quando selecionar um país, tu precisa fazer uma consulta com *ajax* no arquivo que tu faz o *select* no banco para listar os estados.

Nesse arquivo deixei o *id do* pais como `$_POST['pais']`, mas aí tu adapta pro jeito que tu tá definindo o tipo de requisição. Então tu retorna esses resultados para o *ajax* através do `json_encode`.

Por último tu percorre esses dados com um `for` e adiciona eles dentro do *select* de estados.

PHP

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT estado FROM tabela_estados WHERE idpais = $_POST['pais'] ORDER BY estado ASC");
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($results as $res) {
    $estados[] = array(
      'id'  => $res->id,
      'nome' => $res->estado,
  );
}

return json_encode($estados);
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pais').on('change', function() {
      var pais = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
        url: 'estados.php,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { pais : pais },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {    
          var options = '<option value=""></option>';

          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            options += '<option value="' +
              data[i].id + '">' +
              data[i].nome + '</option>';
          }

          $('#estados').html(options);
        }
    });
  });
});
```